# Already define the route but, error is not define

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have already defined the route. But it shows `not defined route` error. Let me explain what I have done in my code.

ROUTE:

```
Route::post('/member/import-single-trades', 'trades\ImportSingleTradesController@tradesImport')
    ->name('member.add-single-trade.import-excel.import_fields');
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('/member/import-single-trades') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Now ERROR is :

> Route [member/import-single-trades] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\development\fresh\ytl\resources\views\member\add-single-trade\import-excel\import.blade.php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you pass the URL of the route then use url() method

```
action="{{ url('/member/import-single-trades') }}"
```

And if you pass the route name then use route() method

```
action="{{ route('member.add-single-trade.import-excel.import_fields') }}"
```

Comment: its perfect answer. thanks so much. @Sunil kumawat can you help me?

Comment: Always Welcome.

Answer (score 2):

web.php

```
Route::get('profile','ProfileController@profile')->name('profile');
Route::post('profile','ProfileController@update_profile')->name('profile');

profile.blade.php
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url('admin/profile') }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" id="profile_frm">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your route name is different that's why you got the error.
try this

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ URL::to('member/import-single-trades') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">


Route::post( 'member/import-single-trades', 'trades\ImportSingleTradesController@tradesImport');
```

Or your form action should be

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('member.add-single-trade.import-excel.import_fields') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```